# Showing bug count or CI build on a TV in the office

Tags: continuous-integration

I recently saw a blog post showing off different displays that some software development shops use for showing their bug count or CI build status on a nice TV in the office.

I can't for the life of me find it now, and I can't find it on google either.

Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Edit: can anyone point me to an example of such a display in use, so I can get an idea of what to implement in our office's system.

(I don't think this belongs on superuser or serverfault either)

-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this one](http://www.panic.com/blog/2010/03/the-panic-status-board/). Don't know if it's exactly the one you had in mind...

Comment: Thanks! That was one of them, and inspired by that someone else had blogged other examples from other companies.

Comment: That was the one I was thinking of too. +1

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you hook up the TV to the build machine and hook into CI/bug tracking via public APIs?

Comment: Yes. My question is if anyone has seen the blog post that was floating around the internet about a month ago, or has screenshots of such systems, I'm looking for ideas as to what to display in our office.